# Apache mod_rewrite condition for hosted domain with SSL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I have five hosted domains with a multi-domain SSL certificate. I cannot write an .htaccess condition that captures both http and https conditions for CNAME www.altdomain.com (a secondary domain). When a user types "https://altdomain.com" in the browser location bar, it shows "connection untrusted" and the URL remains as is. Typing the same with http correctly redirects to https://www.altdomain.com and when the https is omitted, "altdomain.com" is correctly redirected as well.

I am using joomla with a configuration that hides a subdirectory from the URL. The doc root .htaccess file contains this in the custom redirect section:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^altdomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.altdomain.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Activating a joomla SSL plugin while omitting custom redirect rules in .htaccess also works, but "https://" with "altdomain.com" fails to redirect in all cases. Perhaps I should have omitted www from the CNAME but there would be a redirect issue there as well if anyone types www in the URL, and I can't change the CNAME without purchasing a new SSL certificate. If there is no .htaccess solution to this problem as I suspect, please explain why.

Answer (score 0):

The standard redirect between www and non-www URLs works only on the primary domain or for http connections. For secure / https connections on secondary domains, there must be an exact CNAME match on the SSL certificate - redirection to a host name that is not listed as a CNAME on the certificate will not work even if the domain name is the same.

If I want https connections to redirect from altdomain.com to www.altdomain.com and vice-versa on a multi-domain SSL certificate, I have to include both CNAMES in the certificate.  A five-domain SSL certificate is therefore limited to three domains.